# Command History Arrow keys are not working in Command Prompt Windows

Tags: perl, command-prompt

I was trying to run one of the perl files in command prompt from the path where the file in situated.
Once I enter the debug mode, command history down and up arrow keys functionalities are not working.
I have tried many properties settings, currently it is like this
[image]

Please guide me through how to fix this? It is becoming difficult to debug. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: *"Once I enter the debug mode"* : You mean the history inside the Perl debugger? On Linux, I think you have to install [`Term::ReadLine`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine) to get that working. I am not sure if that will work on Windows though

Comment: Thank You, but No, I'm working In windows. I did windows update recently, after that I lost this feature in command prompt. Not sure whether this issue is connected to the windows update.

Answer (score 2):

The prompt you get inside the Perl debugger isn't provided by your shell, so it should not be surprising that it has different command history features to your shell prompt.

The [perldebug](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug) manual page documents the Perl debugger and has a section entitled [Readline Support / History in the Debugger](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug#Readline-Support-/-History-in-the-Debugger) which says this:

> As shipped, the only command-line history supplied is a simplistic one that checks for leading exclamation points. However, if you install the Term::ReadKey and Term::ReadLine modules from CPAN (such as Term::ReadLine::Gnu, Term::ReadLine::Perl, ...) you will have full editing capabilities much like those GNU *readline*(3) provides. Look for these in the *modules/by-module/Term directory* on CPAN. These do not support normal **vi** command-line editing, however.
>
> A rudimentary command-line completion is also available, including lexical variables in the current scope if the `PadWalker` module is installed.
>
> Without Readline support you may see the symbols "^[[A", "^[[C", "^[[B", "^[[D"", "^H", ... when using the arrow keys and/or the backspace key.

So you'll need to install [Term::ReadKey](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadKey) and one of the [Term::ReadLine::*](https://metacpan.org/search?q=term%3A%3Areadline%3A%3A) modules.

Comment: I don't see anything using `Term::ReadKey` (`rg ReadKey /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl5`, `perl-5.36.0`, Linux). And at first glance it (`Term::ReadKey`) being installed makes no difference. And yes, your wording ("one of") does make it clearer what's needed. Which is important if you haven't ever used the debugger with `readline` (don't have a sure way to confirm if it worked out, because e.g. not every command makes its way into history).

Comment: Also the `^D` key works strangely. It doesn't work if pressed right away (at the beginning of the session). Also after `n`, `s` and maybe some others. The reason seems to be that generally `$DB::single` is [reset](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/v5.37.3/lib/perl5db.pl#L3106-L3107) during processing a command. But with these commands `DB::DB()` is supposedly set to be executed [again](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/v5.37.3/lib/perl5db.pl#L3865-L3901) (`$DB::single = 1/2`). Which makes it seem like `^D` is not working.